# Integrating Boost Asio with ZeroMQ, Bad File Descriptor?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, zeromq

I'm trying to integrate Boost Asio with ZeroMQ. The messaging is functional for the first connection, but the program exits with the error 
    `"Bad File Descriptor"`
when the initial connection ends.

I'm using the Boost.Beast example code of the [Async Websocket Server](https://github.com/boostorg/beast/blob/develop/example/websocket/server/async/websocket_server_async.cpp) to make a connection with the client. I then open a ZMQ socket. The client sends a message to the server over a Websocket connection, the message is send over a ZMQ socket to a different server, the server will do some processing, the server sends the message back over ZMQ, and the final message is sent back to the client over the same Websocket connection.

I am using [This Code](https://github.com/iyedb/boost_asio_zeromq/blob/master/asio_zsock.cxx) to integrate Boost with ZMQ. The line of importance is

```
int zfd;
optlen = sizeof (zfd);
zmq_getsockopt (zmq_sock_, ZMQ_FD, &zfd, &optlen);
sock_.assign (boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), zfd);
```

This gets a file descriptor from the ZMQ socket and wraps it with the Boost socket so everything plays nice. However, when the destructor is called:

```
sock_.shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both);
sock_.close();
zmq_close (zmq_sock_);
```

I get an error that there is a `Socket operation on a Non-socket` because it seems that the socket has been closed. If I remove the socket shutdown and close, I get a `Bad File Descriptor` issue with ZMQ. It seems that the `Session` Websocket object is partially destroying the Asio-ZMQ objects. If I remove the destructor entirely, the program doesn't crash, but it does not work properly anymore. i.e. it won't send any more messages over ZMQ.

I've been struggling with this problem for days and I'm hoping that I can get some help. If it helps, my code takes the `my_zmq_req_client` class and integrates it into the Boost.Beast `session` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't looked at the linked library, but this fragment

```
sock_.shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both);
sock_.close();
zmq_close (zmq_sock_);
```

looks suspicious as `sock_.close()` is meddling with a socket that wasn't opened by it. I'd suggest it makes a lot more sense to [*release*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/release.html) the socket on the asio side, instead of closing it, so that ZMQ can continue having the responsibility over creation/destruction.

```
sock_.shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both);
sock_.release();
zmq_close (zmq_sock_);
```

Comment: Incredible. Fixed it immediately. Thanks very much!

Comment: Just as a matter of interest, does the use of `boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4()` matter at all when `zfd` is almost certainly for a pipe (not a network socket)? I'm guessing not.

Comment: @bazza not unless you use the protocol-specific interface(s), like options. I wouldn't be so sure it's about pipes, that makes little sense in the context given by OP.

Comment: @bazza just an afterthought, in case you were /really/ just trying to ask something else (for a friend) you can use the Posix descriptor wrapper for pipes, instead: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/posix/stream_descriptor.html

Comment: @sehe, apologies, I didn't mean to imply that pipes vs tcp had anything to do with the OP's question. I'm pretty sure that the fd from ZMQ is for a pipe, and so casually wondered if there was any kind of need to match that for Boost. Thank you for a comprehensively good answer!